# Let $M$ and $N$ be two $R$-modules such that the bases of both modules have the same cardinality. Show that $M \cong N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $M$ and $N$ be two $R$-modules such that the bases of both modules have the same cardinality. Show that $M \cong N$.

Let $\{u_1, \dots, u_k\}$ be the base for $M$ and $\{v_1, \dots, v_k\}$ be the base for $N$ for $k \in \Bbb N$. For every $m \in M$ we can express it as a linear combination $m = r_1u_1 + \dots r_ku_k$ for some $r_i's \in R$. How should I define $\varphi$ to get that $\varphi(m_1 + m_2) = \varphi(m_1) + \varphi(m_2)$ and $\varphi(rm_1) = r\varphi(m_1)$?

I know that I need to map the basis elements $\varphi(u_i) = v_i$, but I don't know how to map an element $$\varphi(r_1u_1 + \dots r_ku_k)$$ to get the desired homomorphism?

Comment: Map $r_1u_1+\ldots+r_ku_k$ to $r_1v_1+\ldots+r_kv_k$. The same idea carries over even if the bases are of infinite cardinality.

Comment: universal property of free module